# how to check if the pointer of a particular data structure is pointing to another node of the same data structure

Tags: c

This is the structure I defined for my B+ Tree. The function I display returns the number of the not NULL pointers of a node. The problem I'm encountering is that one of the pointers is pointing to:

```
7:i = 4

8: node->pointer[i] = (struct bptree *) 0x1
```

when checked in gdb which is neither a NULL pointer or a pointer to a Bptree node. When actually the answer should be 3. So is there a way to see if the pointer is pointing a Bptree structure or any data structure it is supposed to point to. N is the order of the B+ Tree

```
struct bptree
{
    char **key;
    int nokeys;
    struct bptree* pointer[N];
    int root;
    int leaf;
    struct bptree* parent;
};

typedef struct bptree Bptree;

int noofpointers(Bptree *node)
{
    int i = 0;
    if(node == NULL)
        return i;
    while(node->pointer[i] != NULL)
        i++;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: What is `N` ? Are you reading beyond the bounds of the array ? To better help you, can you create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me. Are you saying that gdb is showing that the value of `node->pointer[4]` is `0x1` ?

Comment: Yes, gdb is showing node->pointer[4] as 0x1 and node->pointer[5] as 0x0(NULL).

Comment: @aaron - In that case you can be pretty sure that pointer[4] is not pointing to anything valid. A pointer value of 0x1 is most likely not a valid value. What is the value of the three valid pointers? It seems you have a bug that write 0x1 to the pointer.

Comment: how can I get rid of that. More than that how can I find out the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in general, no. Pointers don't carry any additional meta information besides their value, at run-time. You cannot inspect memory and figure out what it is holding (you can *try* by decorating your data with magic numbers).

Also, your code is scary since if all the pointers are used, it will run out of bounds. You must make sure `i` is less than `N` in the loop, and exit when all pointers have been checked.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. And my question is more about can I know the memory location that the pointer is pointing to holds a data structure I'm looking for??

Comment: @aaron And I answered that: you cannot. It can't be done. No, there is no way to do that. You must ensure by the program's logic that your pointers point at valid locations (or `NULL`) at all times, if you intend to dereference them.

Comment: Putting a bound on the number of pointers checked has helped my algorithm and it is working. Thank you very much.